# jQuery: how to get value of selected option in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the part of the DOM I'm working with:

```
<tr id="player-row-973">
    <td class="display_name"> Kevin Love </td>
    <td class="position">
    <select id="position" name="position">
      <option value="pf">PF</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
    </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Using jQuery, I'm trying to get the `value` of the position currently selected for the player Kevin Love. I've tried using something such as the following:

`$('#player-row-973').find('#position').value()` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

firstly if you use ID you can directly select it like:

```
$('#position')
```

and get its value like:

```
$('#position').val()
```

but if you want to have multiple select options like this, you better remove the `id` attribute and use `class` or `name`, then you have all these alternatives to get the value:

using `id` attribute:

```
$('#position').val();
$('#position>option:selected').val();
```

using `name` attribute:

```
$('#player-row-973 select[name=position]').val()
$('#player-row-973 select[name=position]>option:selected').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, its `.val()`

```
$('#player-row-973').find('#position').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
$('#player-row-973').find('#position option:selected').val();
```

For some reasons it does not always succeed with `$('#selectId').val()`.